# JMX in Hazelcast Client

Tags: hazelcast, jmx

The option `-Dhazelcast.jmx=true` seems to have no effect if I connect to the cluster as a cient:

```
hzInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

It works in server mode. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you setting the property on the server or the client? Are you expecting the server or the client to access the JMX data?

Comment: Hi @Nicolas , I am setting it in the client, I expect data to show up when I connect with `jconsole` to the local process. If I use `hzInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);` instead of the above it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#monitoring-with-jmx):

> You can monitor your Hazelcast **members** via the JMX protocol

Emphasis mine. As such, you can only get the JMX metrics on a server JVM, from the Hazelcast node it's running.

Comment: Thanks. Did you find any info / or in your experience if this generates any considerable load on the server?

Comment: I don't have enough experience to tell you about the additional load. But, I can tell you it's better to be a bit slower and now where you're heading to than be very fast without any metrics.